# How to add a description to the Goals used by the Goals module?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using the [Goals](http://drupal.org/project/goals) module in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). I'm now displaying all the Goals that were completed by a user on the profile pages in a table that contains the Goals' image and title.

Now, I'd like to explain a bit more what the user exactly achieved by adding an extra column with a description. Adding a direct description to the Goals would be a perfect solution, but as this isn't provided by the module's maintainers, I opened a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2329973).

I know Drupal Answers isn't built to provide patches (although they're very welcome), so I'd like to ask whether there's perhaps another solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by the module's design. I totally forgot that one can go to `Configuration/Goals/Goals/Manage fields` and add a text field there.

Answer (score 1):

**Goals** used by the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module are implemented using fieldable entities. So you can customize goals by adding your own fields, such as:

- descriptions.
- images.
- links to external resources.
- etc.

Head over to its [video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/58425741), and have a look at what is shown starting from around 4:00 where you can see the typical tabs for Goals, such as:

- Manage Fields.
- Manage display.

For more details, refer to its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900452) also.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of this module.